# Ckeditor rails toolbar not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ckeditor

I am trying to run ckeditor in a rails app . I see the textarea field but don't see any toolbars . I installed it as follows

Gemfile

```
gem 'ckeditor'
gem 'paperclip'
```

routes.rb

```
mount Ckeditor::Engine => '/ckeditor'
```

Field on _form

```
 <div class="field">
<%= f.label :description, :ckeditor %><br>
<%= f.cktext_area :description %>
```

In the head of application.html.rb, I have

```
 <%= javascript_include_tag :ckeditor %>
```

application.js is

```
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require ckeditor/override
//= require ckeditor/init
//= require_tree .
```

I removed turbolinks from the project. I did stop and restart the server.

When I looked at the download from https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor it looks like I should have folders such as app\assets  app\controllers etc. I don't see these in my project. I thought that the gem install would handle everything. I'm not sure if that is the problem or not.

Source at the ckeditor field

```
 <div class="field">
    <label for="help_request_description">ckeditor</label><br>
    <textarea name="help_request[description]" id="help_request_description">
</textarea><script>
//<![CDATA[
(function() { if (typeof CKEDITOR != 'undefined') { if (CKEDITOR.instances['help_request_description'] == undefined) { CKEDITOR.replace('help_request_description'); } } else { setTimeout(arguments.callee, 50); } })();
//]]>
</script>
  </div>

    <div class="field">
   <!--   < %= f.label :description, :ckeditor %><br> -->
      < %= f.cktext_area :description,:toolbar=>'Full', :width=>'700px', :height=>'600px' %>

    </div>


  <div class="field">
```

NOTE - the code fragment in the image is because I deliberately disable that code injection with a space for testing. Taking it out will not show the toolbar.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a screenshot? You'll either be seeing the toolbar with no icons, or no toolbar. The answer will depend on the situation

Comment: Richard - I am not seeing any toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

I am almost positive that the ckeditor issue began when I updated Ruby to 2.1.7 from 1.9.x . At the same time, I had issues with my horizontal menu dropdowns not working.

I had to change the line in application.html.erb that referenced turbolinks from 'application' to 'defaults'. That would fix the crash and error message but apparently was causing other issues.

I uninstalled Ruby 2.17 and reinstalled Ruby 2.0. I reinstalled turbolinks and set everything back to the default settings (for turbolinks)  That seems to have resolved the menu dropdown and this issue of the ckeditor toolbars.